# How to make center image bigger when scrolled horizondally?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

When i scroll the collection view horizontally, the centre image should be bigger then other images. how to achieve that?

Comment: Use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: you can get the center image and apply scale transformation on it.

Comment: how to get the centre image from collection view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first give type "custom" to your carousel view type

```
  vwCarousel.type = .custom
```

then, normally create your view in carousel: view for item method like below, belowed frames are my needed frames , you can set your needed frames as per view,

```
 func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {  
var itemView = UIImageView()
itemView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: 
carousel.frame.size.width - 60, height: carousel.frame.size.height))
itemView.image = self.arrAboutPictures[index]
itemView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
itemView.setCornerRadius(clipToBounds: true, radius: 10)

  return itemView
}
```

Now , Main thing is Coming , give CATranform animation to carousel , it has its own method like below , you can set your "Z" by your requirements

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, itemTransformForOffset offset: CGFloat, baseTransform transform: CATransform3D) -> CATransform3D {

    let spacing : CGFloat = 0.15
    let distance : CGFloat = 100
    let clampedOffset = min(1.0, max(-1.0, offset))

    var offset = offset

    let z : CGFloat = CGFloat(-fabs(clampedOffset)) * distance

    offset += clampedOffset*spacing
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset * carousel.itemWidth , 0.5 , z );

}
```

thats it, your custom animation is created . cheeres....[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use icarousel view.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *viewICarousel;
```

use this methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _viewICarousel.dataSource = self;
    _viewICarousel.delegate = self;
    _viewICarousel.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _viewICarousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear; //user different type

    [_viewICarousel reloadData];

    }
    - (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        return (self.view.frame.size.width * 248 / 320);  //Method use for width set of view
    }
    - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
    {
        if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
        {
            return value * 1.164; // Space between view
        }
        return value;
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        return  _arrCampaignData.count;
    }
    - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(nullable UIView *)view
    {
        UILabel *label = nil;
        UIImageView *imgView = nil;

        if (view == nil)
        {
            view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width * 278.0 / 320), _viewICarousel.frame.size.height)];
            view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            CGRect rectImage = view.bounds;
            imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectImage];
            [view addSubview:imgView];
        }
        else
        {
            label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
        }

        imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:41/255.0 green:171/255.0 blue:135/255.0 alpha:0.3];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arrCampaignData[index][KEY_COMPAIGN_NAME]];
        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arrCampaignData[index][KEY_CAMPAIGN_BANNER]];
        [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

        return view;
    }
    - (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
       //select view
    }
```

Hope this is help for you.

Answer (score -2):

you can try [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) and change main image size.