# CollectionView: How to make the cell size bigger for the cell which is at center of the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, collectionview

I want to create a design like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCvKS.png). It is a Camera UI where the user can scroll through different face masks and apply any face mask while recording the video.

I have gone through many URLs like:

[Swift How to get the centre cell in a collectionView and resize it when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741161/swift-how-to-get-the-centre-cell-in-a-collectionview-and-resize-it-when-scrollin)

[How to make center image bigger when scrolled horizondally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415064/how-to-make-center-image-bigger-when-scrolled-horizondally)

But neither of these solutions worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0,40);
        if([collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point] != nil)
        {
            NSIndexPath *centerIndex = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
            if(centerIndex != nil)
            {
                if (indexPath.item == centerIndex.item) {
                    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(nonnull UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    //top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FavImageCollectionViewCell *newCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FavImageCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!newCell)
    {
        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FavImageCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        newCell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    newCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return newCell;
}
```

But here in my code, the application crashes at

> [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point]

It gives error like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

I would really appreciate any kind of suggestions or improvements to my code.

Comment: error says that you did not have any element in array and you try to extract one so remove the array portion and your solution will work

Comment: @chiragshah Thanks for the reply. but it crashes on line `[collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point]` which is the internal method of collection view. Moreover, currently I am creating just a sample so this is not having any arrays. It is statically created for 5 items.

Comment: I think it is crashing because method for cell size is getting called earlier.. before collectionview actually display a cell.

Comment: Do you need to update the size when user will scroll the collection view, to make the newely centered cell bigger?

Comment: @Shubham: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Ok, So your current approach wont work in that case.